# Problem connecting Netbeans to gitHub using private/public key pair

Tags: github, netbeans, netbeans-8

I've been struggling with this now on Debian, while my Mac environment seems to be working, following the same process.

So, I've setup my key pair following the guide here:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys

and following the rest of the guide, verified with;

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

**This is successful to this point**, however when I try and update any of my projects or clone my repositories in Netbeans, I get errors, similar to:

**Incorrect credentials for repository at github.com:xxx43721/testing_sim.git**

The Netbeans dialog is as below and I've tried different variations of the URL format, all with the same results.

[image]

It's worth noting that the above procedure and screen shot is pretty much what I've done on my Mac and have no issues.

Additionally and this proves that there are no issues with the key pair between my computer and **github**. I am able to run the following from the command line successfully;

```
git clone git@github.com:my_user_name/testing_sim
```

so the problem must be with Netbeans and I have tried both the old faithful 8.2 and also 12.0, nether of which will work on Debian 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: The only solution I have for the time being is to use a Personal Access Token, where you would use the _https_ format for the repository url and use the token string in the password field. This does continue to work but it is a bit of a pain, especially when the ssh keys work fine on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Netbeans 13 on Ubuntu. Netbeans is picky when it comes to private key formats. This was my solution.

Create an SSH key with the following settings:
`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C "comment" -m PEM`

Add the public key to Github.

Set up the connection in Netbeans with:
Repository URL: ssh://github.com/user/repo.git
Username: git
Private/Public key: Path to your private key

Notes:

- RSA keys are deprecated by github.
- ed25519 keys (recommended by github) are too new for Netbeans.
- Netbeans requires private keys in PEM format (the public key format is the same).